# FollowSymLinks is enabled for <Directory> however Apache returns HTTP 403 for image request

Tags: magento2, apache2, system-configuration

It seems like I have some generic Apache configuration issue, but I cannot spot the problem.
I have Magento v2.2.7 installed to default Apache document root directory (`/var/www/magento`) under user `magento` (GID `www-data`). The corresponding Apache configuration is the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/magento>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options=All,MultiViews AuthConfig Indexes
</Directory>
```

I haven't changed anything in `.htaccess` files – they are used as provided by Magento installation. For example, `/var/www/magento/.htaccess` contains the following:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
```

"Use Web Server Rewrites" option is enabled, and URL rewrites work appropriately. All resources (JS, CSS, fonts) are loaded correctly both in admin and store, except images that I have uploaded to Magento via admin interface, namely:

- Site logo
- Product images

For example when I request URI `/magento/pub/media/logo/websites/1/logo.jpg`, status HTTP 403 is returned with the following logged to Apache error log:

```
# root@server:~# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Wed Feb 20 10:54:56.588137 2019] [rewrite:error] [pid 24674] [client 189.64.12.201:10934] AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions : /var/www/magento/pub/media/logo/websites/1/logo.jpg, referer: https://www.server.com/magento/
[Wed Feb 20 11:25:24.497872 2019] [rewrite:error] [pid 24698] [client 189.64.12.201:10400] AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions : /var/www/magento/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/aefcd4d8d5c59ba860378cf3cd2e94da/5/2/52681140.jpg, referer: https://www.server.com/magento/home.html
```

Here is the uploaded logo:

```
magento@server:/var/www/magento$ ls -ld pub pub/media pub/media/logo pub/media/logo/websites pub/media/logo/websites/1 pub/media/logo/web
sites/1/logo.jpg                                                                                                                            
drwxr-x--- 1 magento  www-data   176 Feb 17 23:37 pub                                                                                       
drwxrws--- 1 magento  www-data   160 Feb 20 08:57 pub/media                                                                                 
drwxrwsr-x 1 www-data www-data    30 Feb 20 09:03 pub/media/logo                                                                            
drwxrwsr-x 1 www-data www-data     2 Feb 20 09:03 pub/media/logo/websites                                                                   
drwxrwsr-x 1 www-data www-data    16 Feb 20 09:03 pub/media/logo/websites/1                                                                 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 40324 Feb 20 09:03 pub/media/logo/websites/1/logo.jpg
```

When I enable `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

```
<Directory /var/www/magento>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    ...
</Directory>
```

then requests for images start to work, however once reindexing takes place, symlinks are created with `www-data` ownership and Apache refuses to follow them (hence everything breaks down):

```
[Mon Feb 18 11:27:06.360297 2019] [core:error] [pid 12079] [client 189.64.12.201:10400] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/magento/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js, referer: https://www.server.com/magento/control/admin/system_config/index/key/2376d1328b68bd0679181a3c8e78f992e87a39157c80ffa0deadaaa617342843/
```

Site is in default mode:

```
magento@server:/var/www/magento$ ./bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Current application mode: default. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)
```

Any suggestion about how to make images working without enabling `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

How do you fix that? i have the same trouble with my magento, I have the correct permissions, but do the same think.

when i use this command: cd /var/www/html/ && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento

show me some error about permissions, and its because the user is "www-data" and not "magento", the goup its the same www-data.

Comment: As for me I haven't come to any solution, and honestly, haven't debugged it. Actually I am surprised that `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` helps, as it is restricting option.